# Long operation in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I am trying to understand the proper way to perform the following task.

I have a long operation (Database insertion about 10000 rows) after user input. 
I need to return to a user some View that will say that his job is in progress , no need to show progress or something , but I can't freeze the ui for user.

```
public class AuthController : SurfaceController
    {
        public ActionResult LongOpeartion(UserInput model)
          {
              // Long async operation goes here 
              return View();
          }

    }
```

Can anyone please suggest the Right way of firing async Task , or something.
 Thanks.

Comment: Either you start a task and return right away,
or you call that using ajax.

Comment: Ajax is not an option since user arrives this controller from callback of CRM API.

Comment: this link will help you http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use ajax and want to reply right away I think this would be appropriate.

```
public class AuthController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult LongOpeartion(UserInput model)
      {
         Task t = Task.Run( () => {
             // Long async operation goes here 
          } );

          return View();
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Asynchronous Controller will help you in this regards,

please check following link,

[Asynchronous Controller in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/526099/Asynchronous-Controller-in-ASP-NET-MVC)